# How to restart a Tidal agent using APIs

Tags: tidal-scheduler

I am new to Tidal and have to automate the agent restart process using API.
From the architecture stand point, I understand the agents are running on the nodes, so when the tidal master is not able to reach agent, it sends an error message with agent name that is not running. How can I use this information to restart the agent ? Is there any API to restart an agent ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so apparently there is no API to restart Tidal agent. This has to be done through command by logging into the target machine where the agent is running.